# My jumping is way to fast, its over in the blink of an eye

Tags: java, slick2d

the title says alot, ive tried thread.sleep before and it does not help. I want to slow down the jumping command so that you can see the character jump, right now it finishes in the blink of an eye. Please explain how to do this. I use slick2d java, new to java

Thanks for your time!

```
package JavaGame;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Play extends BasicGameState{

    Animation bucky, movingUp, movingDown, movingLeft, movingRight;

    boolean quit = false;
    int[] duration = {400, 100}; //2 tenths of a second and 2 tenths of a second, both in under half a second. Series of image, how long each image lasts  
    //the array of numbers decides the length of the animation
    float buckyPositionX = 0;
    float buckyPositionY = 0;
    float shiftX = buckyPositionX + 540; //Shifting something 320, always letting bucky be in the middle of the screen
    float shiftY = buckyPositionY + 620;
    boolean jumping = false;
    double gravity = 10;
    double jumpingTime = 200;
    float v = shiftY;
    double counter2 = 4;

    public Play(int state){

    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
        Image[] walkUp = {new Image("res/buckysRight.png"), new Image("res/buckysFront.png")}; //Change to jump, add more imagines (same amount of duration as images)
        Image[] walkDown = {new Image("res/buckysFront.png"), new Image("res/buckysFront.png")}; //change last picture to the front will restore it to the front frame ending the animation
        Image[] walkLeft = {new Image("res/buckysLeft.png"), new Image("res/buckysFront.png")};
        Image[] walkRight = {new Image("res/buckysRight.png"), new Image("res/buckysFront.png")};

        //Creating the actual animation, animations defined Animation, bucky bla bla
        movingUp = new Animation(walkUp, duration, false);
        movingLeft = new Animation(walkLeft, duration, false);
        movingRight = new Animation(walkRight, duration, false);
        movingDown = new Animation(walkDown, duration, false);
        bucky = movingDown;
    }


    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
        g.fillRect(buckyPositionX, buckyPositionY, 10000, 50); //Øverste boks
        g.fillRect(buckyPositionX, buckyPositionY + 660, 10000, 70); //Nederste boks
        g.fillRect(buckyPositionX, buckyPositionY + 360, 50, 300); // Bakerste Kant

        bucky.draw(shiftX, shiftY);
        boolean debug = true;

        if(debug == true){
            g.drawString("Buckys X: " + buckyPositionX + "\nBuckys y: " +buckyPositionY, 900, 50);
            g.drawString("Buckys 2 X: " + shiftX + "\nBuckys 2 y: " + shiftY, 900, 100);
        }

        if(quit == true){ //When esc is hit launch the menu.
            g.drawString("Resume (R)", 250, 100);
            g.drawString("Main Menu (M)", 250, 150);
            g.drawString("Quit (Q)", 250, 200);

            if(quit == false){
                g.clear();
            }
        }
    }


    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{
        Input input = gc.getInput();

        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){
            bucky = movingRight;
            buckyPositionX -= .2;
        }

        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){
            bucky = movingLeft;
            buckyPositionX += .2;

            if(buckyPositionX > 492){
                buckyPositionX -= .2;
            }//delta * .1f
        }

        if(shiftY < 620 && jumping != true){
            shiftY += gravity;  
        }

        if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_SPACE)){
            jumping = true;

            while(jumping == true){
                counter2 += 0.0005;
                shiftY = shiftY - (int) ((Math.sin(counter2) + (Math.cos(counter2)))*20);

                if(counter2 >= 7){
                    counter2 = 4;
                    jumping = false;
                }
            }
        }

        //escape
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)){
            quit = true;
        }

        //when the menu is up
        if(quit == true){
            if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_R)){
                quit = false;
            }

            if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_M)){
                sbg.enterState(0);
            }

            if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_Q)){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }   
    }

    public int getID(){
        return 1;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always make game update depending on TIME, so it has same speed on all computers without problem. And it solves your problem too.

```
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException
```

The game container should have something liek this :

```
gc.getTime()
```

Which shows you how much time passed in the last run. If it does not have this, you can use

```
System.nanoTime()
```

Then you only need some int value, where you store your time and you do some update for example only once each 50 milisec.

Answer (score 0):

Since Slick2D uses LWJGL, you will find LWJGL wiki particularly helpful.

This one is great for your question: [LWJGL Basics 4: Timing](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=LWJGL_Basics_4_%28Timing%29)

Aso, try this for a "How to quickly get used to using delta code"

```
private float yRect;

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) throws SlickException {

    yRect += 0.03f * delta;
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    g.pushTransform();
    g.translate(0, yRect);
    g.fillRect(20, 20, 200, 100);
    g.popTransform();
}
```

Make sure to run this example at a reasonable framerate...

```
appgamecontainer.setTargetFrameRate(60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh you do all the jumping calculations in a while loop without rendering.

```
        while(jumping == true){
            counter2 += 0.0005;
            shiftY = shiftY - (int) ((Math.sin(counter2) + (Math.cos(counter2)))*20);

            if(counter2 >= 7){
                counter2 = 4;
                jumping = false;
            }
        }
```

This is not correct. You have to render the image in each round of your jumping loop. Otherwise the jumping calculations will happen but it will not be displayed.

I'm giving this answer hoping your main method is something like this. Or the slick's main method if you are overriding one of their classes.

```
init()
while(true){
    update();
    render();
    doTiming(); // Whatever the method you use for timing in the game loop.
}
```

So what you have to do is put a flag when jumping is happening and block the other movements.

```
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{

        if(jumping){    // Or jumping == true
            counter2 += 0.0005;
            shiftY = shiftY - (int) ((Math.sin(counter2) + (Math.cos(counter2)))*20);
            if(counter2 >= 7){
                counter2 = 4;
                jumping = false;
            }
        }else{
            Input input = gc.getInput();        
            if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){
                bucky = movingRight;
                buckyPositionX -= .2;
            }

            if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){
                bucky = movingLeft;
                buckyPositionX += .2;

                if(buckyPositionX > 492){
                    buckyPositionX -= .2;
                }//delta * .1f
            }

            if(shiftY < 620 && jumping != true){
                shiftY += gravity;  
            }

            if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_SPACE)){
                jumping = true;
            }

            //escape
            if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)){
                quit = true;
            }

            //when the menu is up
            if(quit == true){
                if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_R)){
                    quit = false;
                }

                if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_M)){
                    sbg.enterState(0);
                }

                if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_Q)){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }       
    }
```

So in each round of jumping loop the render method is called. So all the parts in your jump will be displayed.

A suggestion : If you are good at physics use equations of motion instead of using sin and cos things to simulate the jump. I'm not sure how you changed shiftY for the jump. But if you used v=u+at [equation](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1Dkin/u1l6c) you can get it as a real world jump.